# What are the differences between the git and git-core packages?

Tags: git, version-control

Why there is a `git` package and a `git-core` package? Is there any difference?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The `git-core` package is a "dummy" package, which has the `git` package as dependency. This is because the `git-core` package has been renamed to `git`.

The dummy `git-core` package should be safely removable.

In previous releases, it seems git was a virtual package for gnuit (GNU Interactive Tools).

[Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20100401211132/http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/git)

Comment: Source is taking to **Ubuntu Error** page.

Comment: @GauravAgarwal: Thanks for the notification. Source has been replaced with archive.org link.